# How to create big np.zeros matrices?

Tags: numpy, memory-management, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory

When I'm trying to create a numpy matrix in Colab with 12GB of RAM I see memory error:

```
A = np.zeros((644253, 50, 259))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That'd need around 8 GB of memory (`644253 * 50 * 259/1000/1024/1024`). Are you running other processes as well?

Comment: The default type is float64 so 8 bytes per element @kmario23

Comment: If the matrix is sparse, you might want to have a look at the [sparse matrix objects in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ah yes, I forgot to multiply that factor. `8 * 644253 * 50 * 259/1024/1024/1024` = `62.16076277196407` GB. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: One possible alternative is to use `scipy.sparse` if your matrix is sparse. Note that `scipy.sparse` supports only 2d matrix, so you need some sort of trick to deal with your 3d-array (e.g., reshaping your array). It depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default type is np.float64, which is 8 byte. The size in GB is 644253*50*259*8/1024**3 = 62.16GB.  You cannot create such a matrix, not enough memory.  If you really need it, add a lot of swap memory, but it will be very slow comparing to RAM (may be orders of magnitude slower).  You may also try `A = np.zeros((644253, 50, 259), type=np.float32)` or `A = np.zeros((644253, 50, 259), type=np.int8)` or whatever type you need.  This may save memory.

Comment: thank you. It works on usual macbook: https://youtu.be/ZGU5kIG7b2I?t=1599. How Can It Be? There are more than 32k values in the matrix, int8 is too small. Are you sure that there is no any workaround about this problem?

Comment: Maybe your Colab-thing doesn't have as much swap space as your MacBook...

Comment: I believe a `np.memmap` will be filled with zeros automatically. Therefore you can also use `np.memmap('myTempFile.bin', 'uint32', 'w+', 0,  (644253,50,259))`. 32k is `int16` by the way. If you max is smaller than 64k, consider `uint16`